# Can't run unit tests with RobolectricTestRunner and Koin

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, koin

I have a test class with `RobolectricTestRunner` which I use for getting application context and also I extend one class with `KoinComponent`. When I started my test it returned `java.lang.IllegalStateException: KoinApplication has not been started` and points to my class that extends `KoinComponent`. I tried to start Koin in `setUp()` method with loading modules and removed Robolectric but in this way it can't find application context. Is there a way to write unit test with Robolectric and Koin?

Comment: Why does your test class extend a class that extends KoinComponent?

Comment: @Ricardo You misunderstood me, I have another class(BroadcastReceiver) that extends KoinComponent not test class

Answer (score 1):

[As you can read here](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/503#issuecomment-504642125), `BroadcastReceivers` declared in the AndroidManifest get created before your Application's `onCreate`. Therefore, Koin is not yet initialized. A workaround for that is to create a Helper for your Broadcast Receiver and initialize the Helper lazy:

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    // Broadcast Receivers declared in the AndroidManifest get created before your Application's onCreate.
    // The lazy initialization ensures that Koin is set up before the broadcast receiver is used
    private val koinHelper: BroadcastReceiverHelper
        by lazy { BroadcastReceiverHelper() }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        koinHelper.onReceive(context, intent)
    }
}

class BroadcastReceiverHelper : KoinComponent {

    private val myClassToInject: MyClassToInject by inject()

    fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```